# Display custom post type edit and list screens as separate submenu items

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type called `meeting` and I want to add its edit and list screens as separate submenu items under a custom menu item slug `meetings_settings`.

Here is my current menu setup

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wf_meetings_menu');
function wf_meetings_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Meetings', 'Meetings', 'manage_options', 'meetings_menu', 'meetings_settings');
    add_submenu_page('meetings_menu', 'Meetings Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'meetings_menu_settings', 'meetings_settings');
    // meetings list screen goes here
    add_submenu_page('meetings_menu', 'All Meetings', 'All Meetings', 'manage_options', 'meetings_menu_all', 'meetings_all');
    // meetings edit screen goes here
    add_submenu_page('meetings_menu', 'New Meeting', 'New Meeting', 'manage_options', 'meetings_menu_new', 'meetings_new');
}
```

From research I see you can add a custom post type as a submenu by setting `show_in_menu => 'edit.php?post_type=meeting'` on the custom post type, and then setting the draw function for the submenu item to `'edit.php?post_type=meeting'`. I'm a little confused with this part, because wouldn't that only include the edit screen for that post type? There are TWO screens for a custom post type: the edit screen and the list screen (plus categories and tags but I don't need those in this case).

How do you differentiate between the two and add both the edit and list screens for a custom post type as submenu items of a regular admin menu item like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the add_submenu_page function is the parent slug which in this case is `'edit.php?post_type=meeting'` in your scenario you'd want to add a custom link that links to the post type edit screen. so you would add a function in functions.php that would add the link manually

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'meetings_admin_menu');
function meetings_admin_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $new_url = 'post-new.php?post_type=meeting';
    $all_url = 'edit.php?post_type=meeting';
    $submenu['meetings_menu'][] = array('New Meeting', 'edit_posts', $new_url);
    $submenu['meetings_menu'][] = array('All Meetings', 'edit_posts', $all_url);
}
```

note: the second paramater in the `$submenu array()` is permissions. change accordingly

and now you only need your `add_menu_page` function.

Comment: Okay, so that explains the edit screen, but how do I get the list screen in its own page? Would it be something like `$submenu['meetings_menu'][] = array('Add Meetings', 'edit_posts', 'edit.php?post_type=meeting');`?